# How to create labelled TextField in React MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I wanted to know if we have or we can create a labeled text field in react using material-UI[image: Example of Semantic UI]

where the sub-domain part is prefilled.
Example of Semantic UI.
[Semantic UI](https://codesandbox.io/s/idj78?module=/example.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this, you can use `InputProps` in TextField.

```
  <div>
    <TextField
      InputProps={{
        startAdornment: (
          <InputAdornment position="start">http://</InputAdornment>
        )
      }}
    />
  </div>
```

See the demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-un8xk